# Parsing JSON using Jquery in dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, parsing

I am building a specific location selector using dropdowns. I need 3 dropdown for the same. 
Now i got the json and trying to parse it accordingly but i am having some problems. Here is small part of json i am using.

```
{
"Chandigarh": {
    "CHANDIGARH": ["Sector 21 (Chandigarh)", "Sector 22 (Chandigarh)", "Sector 23 ( Chandigarh)", "Sector 26 (Chandigarh)", "Sector 29 (Chandigarh)", "Sector 30"]}
 "Andhra Pradesh": {
    "EAST GODAVARI": ["D Vemavaram", "Gangavaram", "GSL Medical College", "Konthamuru", "Navara", "Satellite City"]
      "CHITTOOR": ["Appa Rao Street", "Madanapalle Spinning Mills Gds", "Akkurthi", "Chiyyavaram", "Chodavaram", "Gottipudi", "Kasaram", "Muchivolu", "Obulayapalle"]}
}
```

So i am trying to parse states into one dropdown , and based on states sub-region can be selected , and based on sub-regions city name can be selected.
for eg. If i select "Andhra Pradesh" on one dropdown , other must show "East Godavri" and "chittoor" and whichever i select then must show it's cities in third dropdown.
So far i have tried using jquery getjson

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
console.log(data);
$.each(data, function(index, value) {


  $("#state").append(
    '<option value="' + index + '">' + index + "</option>"
  );
});


 });



 $("#state").change(function() {


countryCode = $("#state").val();

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {

  $('#sub').append('<option value="">Please select your region</option>');
  $.each(data.response.venue.countryCode, function(index, value) {

    $("#sub").append(
      '<option value="' + index + '">' + index + "</option>"
    );
  });
});


 });
```

I am getting all the city names but not sub-regions , Anyone who can help me

Comment: Is the JSON that you posted accurate?  If so, is there any way you can change the structure so it's more meaningful?  I think that might be part of the problem, because you have one large object that has multiple properties that have state names, and those have sub-properties with the names of sub-regions.  My point is that, unless you know what the data is, you can't get an idea of what the words in the JSON represent.  To you, it makes sense, but to me, it looks confusing, and that's an issue.  If you need an example, let me know.  I can only type so much here.

Answer (score 0):

First let's restruction JSON data to this for contain an option id (To use `id` for option's value)

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Chandigarh",
    regions: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "CHANDIGARH",
        areas: [
          { id: 3, name: "Sector 21 (Chandigarh)" },
          { id: 4, name: "Sector 22 (Chandigarh)" },
          { id: 5, name: "Sector 23 ( Chandigarh)" },
          { id: 6, name: "Sector 26 (Chandigarh)" },
          { id: 7, name: "Sector 29 (Chandigarh)" },
          { id: 8, name: "Sector 30" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    name: "Andhra Pradesh",
    regions: [
      {
        id: 10,
        name: "EAST GODAVARI",
        areas: [
          { id: 11, name: "D Vemavaram" },
          { id: 12, name: "Gangavaram" },
          { id: 13, name: "GSL Medical College" },
          { id: 14, name: "Konthamuru" },
          { id: 15, name: "Navara" },
          { id: 16, name: "Satellite City" }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 17,
        name: "CHITTOOR",
        areas: [
          { id: 18, name: "Appa Rao Street" },
          { id: 19, name: "Madanapalle Spinning Mills Gds" },
          { id: 20, name: "Akkurthi" },
          { id: 21, name: "Chiyyavaram" },
          { id: 22, name: "Chodavaram" },
          { id: 23, name: "Gottipudi" },
          { id: 24, name: "Kasaram" },
          { id: 25, name: "Muchivolu" },
          { id: 26, name: "Obulayapalle" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Update the fetch code to save data to variable.

```
var states;

$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
  states = data; // Save data to variable, so no need to fetch data everytime user change the select
  $("#state").html(`<option>Select State..</option>`);
  $("#region").html(`<option>Select region..</option>`);
  $("#area").html(`<option>Select area..</option>`);
  $.each(states, function (index, state) {
    $('#state').append(`<option value="${state.id}">${state.name}</option>`);
  });
});
```

Then assign event to select

```
$("#state").bind("change", function() { // When select state change
  let state = states.find(s => s.id == $(this).val());

  // set region options

  $("#region").html(`<option>Select region..</option>`);
  $.each(state.regions, function(index, region) {
    $("#region").append(`<option value="${region.id}">${region.name}</option>`);
  });

  $("#area").html(`<option>Select area..</option>`);
});

$("#region").bind("change", function() { // When select region change
  let region = states
    .map(s => s.regions)
    .flat()
    .find(r => r.id == $(this).val());

  // set area options

  $("#area").html(`<option>Select area..</option>`);
  $.each(region.areas, function(index, area) {
    $("#area").append(`<option value="${area.id}">${area.name}</option>`);
  });
});
```

Here for the full example

https://codesandbox.io/s/5k87rkr16p

Comment: Hey , really appreciate your help and this works perfectly , i just want to know is there any way to restructure the json , other than manually doing it line by line.

Comment: Where is your data comes from ? Database or json files ?

Comment: I have a big json file.